# Why I'm getting this Error: setRawMode EIO while running npm start or pm2?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, linux, npm, pm2

today I uploaded new changes to my React project on a Linux server, and suddenly I get this error:

```
Error: setRawMode EIO at ReadStream.setRawMode (tty.js:78:31)
```

No idea why, my changes were super minimal. I was working on solving a bug using a '?' to prevent something from happening in my logic, and then this error appeared. I reverted changes but no luck.

Versions in my project:

- react: 17.0.1
- npm: 6.14.15
- node: 14.17.6

I hope someone can assist me with this issue.

I already tried:

1. Cleaned cache.
2. Reinstalled node_modules and package-lock-json
3. Checked disk space (~17GB free).

**UPDATE**:
This error is causing me a 503 Service Unavailable:
[image]